# What happens on integer overflow for auto-increment primary key?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when auto_increment on integer column reaches the max_value in databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615417/what-happens-when-auto-increment-on-integer-column-reaches-the-max-value-in-datab)

Hi,

I have a mysql database, and a table which stores gamerooms for a multiplayer game. I have an integer priamry key auto increment setup for the game ids. So each time a new game is hosted, it just gets the next integer id as its game id. When I game is over, I remove the record from the table. I'm wondering what happens if I ever get to max_int games created - will mysql spin back around to index 0 for the next game record that gets created?:

```
id (int, primary, auto-inc)
--------------------------
       255
       256
       ...
       ...
       4,294,967,296
       what happens on next insert?
```

Honestly I'm not going to get to 4,294,967,296 games, just curious as to what happens. Again, I'm removing completed games from the table, so in theory I would never have more than max_int records in there at any time, but I could spin up to that counter value over time.

Thanks

Comment: exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615417/what-happens-when-auto-increment-on-integer-column-reaches-the-max-value-in-datab)

Comment: @eykanal when posting duplicates I think it's most helpful to use the full like or link the title of the question

Comment: in response to Matthew - duplicate of "[What happens when auto_increment on integer column reaches the max_value in databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615417/what-happens-when-auto-increment-on-integer-column-reaches-the-max-value-in-datab)"

Answer (score 0):

In some older versions of MySQL (e.g., 5.1.31) [MySQL crashes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43203). Nowdays a "generic autoincrement failure (ERR 1467)" is reported (same link, resolution).