# What happens when auto increment primary key in MySQL comes to maximum

Tags: mysql, int, primary-key, auto-increment

I have auto increment, primary key in MySQL called ID and it is INT.
As my app grows and I'm getting more users they are making more entries. What happens when my INT comes to its maximum value 2 147 483 647?
Can I just switch to BIGINT?

Comment: why don't you use BIGINT at first place?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615417/what-happens-when-auto-increment-on-integer-column-reaches-the-max-value-in-data

Comment: Well cause my app is now very small and I thought it would be just enough to use INT.
It is quite similar question. thanks

Comment: You're only 7% of the way to overflowing. Are you sure it's time to freak out? Only Facebook and Twitter have literal *billions* of users. You'll need to have 6 users sign up *per second* for the next ten years straight to exhaust it.

Comment: I'm not freaking out, I would just like to know what happens. It's not just about users, but entries they make, for example inserting data in database

Comment: It may be helpful to you, I created a couple of SQL scripts at https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools that tell you how close you are to overflowing your auto-increment columns and any other INT columns.  See files `pk-full-ratio.sql` and `int-full-ratio.sql`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`MySQL` official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) states that :

> When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next
>   attempt to generate a sequence number fails. Use the UNSIGNED
>   attribute if possible to allow a greater range.

And yes, you can switch the types of the `auto_increment` value. On this point, the documentation advises to use :

> [...] the smallest integer data type for the AUTO_INCREMENT column
>   that is large enough to hold the maximum sequence value you will need.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can alter the table and change from INT to BIGINT without problems.

Also, you may need to change the datatype wherever it is as an FK

Comment: +1 Yes, and it's worth mentioning that you chould change the FK data types *before* upgrading the PK they reference.  Otherwise you could create PK values that can't be referenced by child tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a personal experience I just had about this.

Using Nagios + Check_MK + NDOUtils. NDOUtils stores all the checks in a table called nagios_servicechecks. The primary key is an `auto_increment int signed`.

What happens with MySQL when this limit is ranged? Well, in my case, MySQL deleted all the records but the last one. The table is now almost empty. Everytime a new record is inserted the old one is deleted.

I don't why this happens, but the fact is that I lost all my records.

IDOUtils, used with Icinga (not Nagios), fixed this issue changing int by a bigint.