# Is there any way to tell MySQL not to throw when an auto_increment field overflows?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615417/what-happens-when-auto-increment-on-integer-column-reaches-the-max-value-in-data) question, MySQL throws when an auto_increment field overflows. However, in my case I want to auto-purge old data. Is there any way for me to tell MySQL not to throw when the field overflows? I have declared a PK on a auto_increment field.

Comment: Add an insert trigger that will truncate the table once it reach the maximum value-1 (to avoid the overflow) perhaps?

Comment: Bigint is quite big especially unsigned The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615  you will have to move your server quite a lot much faster than you reach the end.

Comment: @nbk my design is to use a 4 byte int and auto-purge old records.

Comment: Change it to bigint. even when you implement a trigger you have to lock the table reassign new ids(from 0)  and set the autpoincrement field, and i believe most experts will tell you it is quite a challenge and not recommended  but doable.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you purge old records, the auto-increment will never recycle old id values. It will only increase. Even if you try to set the auto-increment back to the start:

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

You will see if you `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` that it ignores your request to set the value to 1, and it bumps it up to MAX(id)+1.

Unless you fully empty the table with `TRUNCATE TABLE`, you cannot benefit from purging old records.

Just use a `BIGINT` if you are concerned about running out of `INT` values.